# Get all subfolders of a specific public folder

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to get all subfolders of a specific public subfolder.

The problem I face is that "Deep traversal queries are not allowed on public folders." so I am a bit lost at how to do that now.

Here is my code:

```
Function FindAllSubfolders(){
    $tfTargetidRoot = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::PublicFoldersRoot)
    $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$tfTargetidRoot)

    $FolderPath = "/mydomain.com/parentfolder"
    $pfArray = $FolderPath.Split("/")
    for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $pfArray.Length; $lint++) {
        $pfArray[$lint]
        $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1)
        $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$pfArray[$lint])
        $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView)
        if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){
            foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){
                $tfTargetFolder = $folder               
            }
        }
    }
    
    $folderview = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(10000)
    $folderview.PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
    $folderview.PropertySet.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName)
    $folderview.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep
    $folderfindResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.id, $folderview)
    return $folderfindResults
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this with EWS is you need to do a Shallow traversal of each folder, process the results if that subfolder has child folder then do a Shallow traversal of that child and so on until you get the whole tree. Public folders can get complicated eg if you then want to start access the content of the folder it possible that the child folder maybe located on different Public Folder mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you can try this:

```
$result = Get-PublicFolder -Identity "/mydomain.com/parentfolder" -Recurse -ResultSize Unlimited -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{            
        FolderPath   = $_.Identity
        DisplayName  = $_.DisplayName
        EmailAddress = if ($_.MailEnabled) {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToLower()} else {$null}
    }
}

# show the results
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or Out-GridView if you prefer

# save as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\path\to\PublicFolders.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I don't have access to the "Get-PublicFolder" function. I only use the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` for all those functions. Or is this function also somewhere in that dll?